# Express req.body properties are empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I have a simple code in node js, both on the client and on the server side. The client sends via `axios`, and the server sends via `express`.

relevant client code:

```
      let url = root_path+'detect/?model_type='+algorithm
      let object = {object: [train_object, anomaly_object]}
      return axios.post(url, object).then((res) => console.log(res.data));
```

complete server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const model = require('../model/SimpleAnomalyDetector')

const serverPATH = '/api/detect'

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  next();
});

app.post(serverPATH, (req, res)=> {
  let object = req.body.object;
  let algorithm = req.query.model_type
  console.log(object[0]);
  console.log(object[1]);
  console.log(algorithm);
  var got = model.get_anomalies(object[0], object[1], algorithm)
  console.log()
  //res.send(got);
})

app.listen(9876);
```

The client object is made of a lot of inner objects. When I print the code the sets structure is good, but all the fields are empty. (Also if I try to iterate on the various fields it doesn't work, so I know it's empty).

Any idea? it seems to me I added everything

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the call function an async for your client.

ex:

```
async function callAxios() {
    let url = root_path+'detect/?model_type='+algorithm
    let object = {object: [train_object, anomaly_object]}
    const resp = await axios.post(url, object);
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: I have added that and the async function, I suppose it's more correct now so thank you, but still getting the same issue :(